# Third parameter (kwargs) sklearn fit() function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm quite new to scikit-learn and I have a question about the fit() function. I tried to look for information on the internet but couldn't find much.
In an assignement I have to create a dict of parameters passed to the fit function of a classifier, which means the function will take 3 arguments (X, y, kwargs). What parameters is this dictionary supposed to have? Apparently those are hyper parameters for the fit function. Online I only found information for xgbooster but I'm not supposed to use that, only classifiers from sklearn.

I also found online that fit can take a dictionary called **fit_params but there is nothing about the parameters the function might take.

I hope my question is clear, thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The model hyperparameters are not arguments to the `fit` function, but to the model class object that you need to create beforehand.

If you have a dictionary with parameters that you want to pass to your model, you need to do things this way (here with a Logistic Regression):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
params = {"C":10, "max_iter":200}
LR = LogisticRegression(**params)
```

Now that you have created the model specifying the hyperparameters, you can proceed and fit it with your data.

```
LR.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently the dictionary is to pass parameters that need to be specified for some classifiers for the fit function (mainly sample_weight, or check_input...)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used scikit-learn before, but you can get the docs of a function that you are unsure about by using the `__doc__` method. The `fit()` method of an estimator returns this for its `__doc__` method:

```
Fit the SVM model according to the given training data.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)                 or (n_samples, n_samples)
            Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples
            and n_features is the number of features.
            For kernel="precomputed", the expected shape of X is
            (n_samples, n_samples).

        y : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
            Target values (class labels in classification, real numbers in
            regression)

        sample_weight : array-like of shape (n_samples,), default=None
            Per-sample weights. Rescale C per sample. Higher weights
            force the classifier to put more emphasis on these points.

        Returns
        -------
        self : object

        Notes
        -----
        If X and y are not C-ordered and contiguous arrays of np.float64 and
        X is not a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix, X and/or y may be copied.

        If X is a dense array, then the other methods will not support sparse
        matrices as input.
```

I ran this to get that output:

```py
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
print(clf.fit.__doc__)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I guess there is no 3rd input then, I will try with the different classifiers!